# Scala Play - Action.async with BodyParser - Exception Handling

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, action, body-parser

I am using Scala with Play for my microservice.  It has a Controller that uses the Action.async construct with a custom body parser.  Here's a sample code:

```
def crud(param: String) = Action.async(SomeCustomBodyParser) { implicit request =>
    try {
      <some code>
    } catch {
      case _ => <Exception Handling logic>
    }
}
```

The issue with this code is that in case of an exception in `SomeCustomBodyParser`, it does not get handled in the catch block.  I tried a few approaches where I extract it outside and then handle it manually, but the exception is not caught correctly.   The code of Action.async suggests that it takes a block of code and executes it a separate context.  I am unclear exactly how it works.

How can I handle the exception and spit out a better exception message.

Answer (score 1):

The `Action.async` has to be given a `Future[Result]`, which can be completed either with a successful `Result` or a failure.

Any `failed` `Future` there results in an error HTTP response.

```
Action.async { Future.failed(new Exception("Foo") }
```

The way such error is formatted can be cistomized.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to use **synchronous** error handler to handle **asynchronous** error. `try catch` can only handle synchronous errors. `Future[_]` is asynchronous by nature and it will, if any, throw error after your `try catch` statement has already been executed (and possibly in a different thread).

Instead, in scala, we make error handling explicit by using a data structure like `Option` or `Either` or `\/` from scalaz. All these **wrappers** form Monad.

In most asynchronous server setting, what you want is `Future` with `Either` inside (or right-biased variant like `\/` from scalaz.) This way, you abstract over both asynchronity and error handling. Since both wrappers are monads, you can combine them using **Monad Transformers**. This is a deep topic and requires quite a bit of learning if you are not familiar with it but the gist of such data structure would be something like the following:

```
class Task[E, A] {
  def flatMap[U](f: A => Task[E, U]): Task[E, U] = ??? // Use monad transformer here.
}
```

where `E` represents the type of your custom errors - you probably will represent them through algebraic data type like `sealed trait` with lots of `case class` and `A` is your value type.

Comment: The problem here is that `SomeCustomBodyParser` throws an exception, and the try/catch is not run at all. Whether or not it would have been executed asynchronously is irrelevant, as it isn't executed.

Comment: For the record, ```Either``` is not a monad in scala.

Answer (score 0):

If your BodyParser throws an exception, or fails for some other reason, then any code inside the Action will not execute. The nature of `async` is irrelevant here.

For instance, the `System.exit` in the code below never runs as the BodyParser **always** returns an exception.

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.Future

class Application @Inject() extends Controller {

  def crud(param: String) = Action.async(
    parse.error[String](Future.failed(new RuntimeException("oh noes!")))
  ) { req =>
    System.exit(0)
    ???
  }

}
```

This code generates this stacktrace:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: oh noes!]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:254) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:180) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
```

And the stacktrace says there is a `DefaultHttpErrorHandler` that gets called with exceptions thrown from a BodyParser.

The documentation for [ScalaErrorHandling](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaErrorHandling) has examples of customising this, or writing your own one.